# specific delta need to merge on git from one branch to another

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches b1 and b2 on git.

I have made changes lets say c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 though respected bug b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6  bug number on branch b1,
I want to merge only change  c1 c3 c4  respected bug b1 b3 b4 to branch b2.
how to do it through git command line and if conflicts come how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your commits aren't in a position where they can be taken with a merge command, so your best bet is `git cherry-pick`.  Use like this:

```
$ git checkout b2
$ git cherry-pick c1 c3 c4
```

If there are conflicts, you'll be prompted to resolve them interactively.

There won't be any tracking that they're in, so if you end up merging later on, those will show up as conflicts.1

Comment: Another question i have.I have branch b1 and  made changes c1 whihc have delta  lets say 3 files f1 f2 f3 ,I want only changes related to f1 to another branch b2,